# sfdx update stopped

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

I am try to fix the 'Component conversion failed. Directory does not contain a valid dx project' error. I was told to try to update the sfdx cli. I ran the sfdx update command in vs code and now it has stopped at 115.8MB / 124.1MB what do I do it has been on 115.8 for about 15 minutes now.

Comment: I've had this struggle too (with it usually getting stuck in the 20-30 MB range), though only on my work computer (works just fine on my personal computers). Might be worth reaching out to your IT/Security team to see if there's a network or policy issue that's impacting this.